# When using the builtin settings sync on vscode, where are the actual files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the builtin [setting sync with vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) (not the extension), I've successfully synced, yet I do not see the actual files anywhere through github. Do these files exist somewhere that is accessible through github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell the files are not accessible through github, obviously they are at the root of the repo in `.vscode/`, but I'd love to actually see the backed up version.

The way I handled this with vim was to add a source command in the .vimrc, then link that to it's own github repo.

I guess I'll have to just trust that github and vscode have it handled